# Targets and dependencies in Makefiles compilation

Tags: makefile

I came across a makefile which contained the below code. However i am not  able to understand the first line  `$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp`, what are the dependencies exactly?

```
$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp

@$(PRINTF) "$(MESG_COLOR)Compiling: $(NO_COLOR) $(FILE_COLOR) %25s$(NO_COLOR)" "$(notdir $<)"
@$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD 2> temp.log || touch temp.err
@if test -e temp.err; \
then $(PRINTF) $(ERR_FMT) $(ERR_STRING) && $(CAT) temp.log; \
elif test -s temp.log; \
then $(PRINTF) $(WARN_FMT) $(WARN_STRING) && $(CAT) temp.log; \
else printf "${OK_COLOR}%30s\n${NO_COLOR}" "[OK]"; \
fi;
@$(RM) -f temp.log temp.err
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). It can be used to build any of the targets in `$(OBJS)`, and constructs the names of the prerequisite(s) accordingly.

```
SRCDIR = sources
OBJDIR = objects
OBJS = objects/foo.o objects/bar.o objects/baz.o

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @echo the target is $@, the prereq is $<
```

If you call this rule with "make objects/foo.o", Make will 1) recognize that this rule applies, since the desired target is a member of the rule's list of targets, 2) match the target name "objects/foo.o" against the target pattern "objects/%.o" to obtain the stem "foo", 3) put that stem into the prereq pattern "sources/%.cpp" to obtain the name of the prereq, "sources/foo.cpp".

Answer (score 1):

This is a *static pattern rule*.  Basically it means "for each word in `$(OBJS)`, define an explicit rule where the target pattern `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` matches the word and the prerequisite is the expansion of the pattern `$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp`".

So if `OBJS` is equal to `$(OBJDIR)/foo.o $(OBJDIR)/bar.o $(OBJDIR)/baz.o`, then the static pattern rule is equivalent to writing this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/foo.o : $(SRCDIR)/foo.cpp
        @$(PRINTF) ...
        ...
$(OBJDIR)/bar.o : $(SRCDIR)/bar.cpp
        @$(PRINTF) ...
        ...
$(OBJDIR)/baz.o : $(SRCDIR)/baz.cpp
        @$(PRINTF) ...
        ...
```